# Using deep learning on graphs

Tags: deep-learning, graphs

I have directed graphs with each vertex has some label in "class01_01.gml" format. There are multiple such classes. I need to do multi class classification on these files using deep learning.

Note that each graph in a particular class has different set of vertices.

Is anyone familiar how to apply deep learning in this context?

**PS**: I'm not that familiar in applying deep learning on graphs.

Answer (score 3):

One of the most popular ways of doing classification on graphs is through graph convolutional networks. By running a convolution over the nodes of a graph, the neural net is able to learn the local neighborhoods of the graph. The seminal example is probably the paper Semi-Supervised Classification with Graph Convolutional Networks  by Kipf and Welling. https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.02907